# Trying to get all the process table

Tags: php, ssh, putty

I'm trying to print the whole process table with php (Actually I'm trying to print all the php processes that are running on my server). This is the code I'm using:

```
var_dump(exec("ps -A | grep php"));
```

When I start the php file, it returns me its own PID but not the others that are already running. I've checked through ssh console and there are 7, and that code prints me just 1 and completelly different to the others PID's.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need `ps -Ax | grep ph[p]`

Comment: I've already tested with `ps -A | grep php`, `ps auwx`. These 2 returned me the value of the process associated to that php file. I've also tested right now `ps -A | grep ph[p]` and gives me back the same thing that the other 2

Comment: These processes are being created from a cron task, so I've tried to create it manually on the browser but I don't see them as well

Comment: You forgot the `x` option; otherwise it only shows the foreground tasks.

Comment: I missed in my last comment but yes I took it in consideration! Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at [PHP Manual: getmypid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php)

```
function countProcesses($scriptName) 
{ 
    // ps aux|grep "[u]pdate.php"|wc -l 
    $first    =    substr($scriptName, 0, 1); 
    $rest    =    substr($scriptName, 1); 
    
    $name    =    '"['.$first.']'.$rest.'"'; 
    $cmd    =    "ps aux | grep $name | wc -l"; 
            
    $result    =    exec($cmd); 
            
    return $result; 
}
```

This function returns the number of processes are already running so I just call `echo countProcesses('php6');` and it brings me back the amount of processes running as php6.